# Express.js render html with data from a ssh call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async.js

I'm trying to get data of list of files from a remote server and pass that to my view as below.

```
exports.testbed_files_get = function(req, res, next){

    var tb_files = '';
    var ssh = new SSH({
        host: 'IP',
        user: 'user',
        pass: 'pwd'
    });

    async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            ssh
            .exec('ls /opt/files', {
                out: function(stdout) {
                    console.log(stdout);
                    tb_files = stdout
                }
            }).start();
        },
    ],
    function(err, results) {
        console.log('tb_files : ', tb_files);
        res.render('testbed_info', {testbed_files: tb_files});
    })

}
```

But, the simple-ssh methods I used above are getting executed asynch and populating the tb_files not as expected. Please suggest how can I achieve this requirement.

Comment: `tb_files` is `empty string` ?

Comment: I'm declaring as an empty string. Later it gets populated with a list of files. I want to split with \n and put it an array.